# Cursor giving null pointer exception android with preloaded database

Tags: android, database, listview, cursor, nullpointerexception

This is the class Db.java

```
package calc.three;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Db extends ListActivity {
private SQLiteDatabase newDb;
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
public ListAdapter adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    openDatabase();

    Cursor c = newDb.rawQuery("SELECT _id, organisation FROM shoplist", null);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, c, new String[] { "organisation" },  new int[] { android.R.id.list });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    //inserttodata();
    myDbHelper.close();
}

private long inserttodata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("id", "112");
    cv.put("organisation","test" );
     return newDb.insert("shoplist", null, cv);
}

private void openDatabase() {

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();


    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
System.out.println("failed to open");
        throw sqle;

    }
    //String[] columns= new String[]{"_id", "Organisation"};
    //cursor = newDb.query("Shop", columns, null, null, null, null, null);

}

}
```

This the DataBaseHelper class

```
package calc.three;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/calc.three/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "charity.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory c = null;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, c , SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
   // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
   // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

The XMl layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dip" >
</ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

I am not trying to do much here. I shipped a .db file in the assets folder coppying it which happens successfully...after the copy is created, i opened the .db file from data/data/calc.three/database in the sqlite browser and i have the table there.

but i cant seem to run the application it force closes and gives me a nullPointerException at the line where a pass a rawQuery to the Cursor i run the program without that line and there is no error but i cant display the data in the list view . Please help i have been stuck on this one for past 3 days.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `newDb`…  you declared it but it is still null when you try to use it, giving you the error.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i do that

Comment: I think you were right not getting the error now but there is something new coming up with the above code
android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: You have the id backwards.  It needs to be `android:id="@id/android:list"`

Comment: That did not work either...i m saving the data into an array and displaying it using the array adapter now....Thanks for all the Help man.... I might trouble you again if i have any such problem.. Hope you wont mind :-)